# Windows Form c# - TreeView: unselect item when clicking outside of tree

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a treeview, with several nodes. If I click OUTSIDE the tree, I want the current selected node to be deselected.
But I cannot find the event to trigger, if I click in the white space, the currently selected node remains selected

Comment: if(clickedoutsidetree) treeview.selectedItem = null;
use the click event of the object oustide the tree or something..

Comment: Provide you code snippet for accurate answer.

Comment: hi rmjoia. sorry, do you know the event to trigger when click in the white space of the treeview?

Answer (score 6):

For some reason `<citation needed>` `MouseClick` will not work when clicking an empty part of a `TreeView` control. But `MouseDown` does:

```
private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hit = treeView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    if (hit.Node == null)
    {
        treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
    }
}
```

If you also want to deselect when the `TreeView` looses `Focus` you can code a suitable  event:

```
private void treeView1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
}
```

**Update**

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` should be avoided for the `Enter` and `Leave` events:

> The GotFocus and LostFocus events are low-level focus events that are
>   tied to the WM_KILLFOCUS and WM_SETFOCUS Windows messages. Typically,
>   the GotFocus and LostFocus events are only used when updating UICues
>   or when writing custom controls. Instead the Enter and Leave events
>   should be used for all controls except the Form class, which uses the
>   Activated and Deactivate events. For more information about the
>   GotFocus and LostFocus events, see the WM_KILLFOCUS and WM_KILLFOCUS
>   topics.

Note that by default `HideSelection` is on, so when the `TreeView` loses Focus the selection is hidden but still valid.

Comment: Leave, *never* LostFocus.

Answer (score 1):

Before I give my answer, I just would like to tell you that you should demonstrate that you tried and at least give an example to replicate the problem, in your case, the code to add a treeview in the form. None of those things were done! Anyways, here's one possible solution. If this doesn't work for you, it means you have to play around with the events and choose the most appropriate one for your case

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    treeView1.Nodes.Add("a");
    treeView1.Nodes.Add("b");
    treeView1.Nodes.Add("c");

    treeView1.LostFocus += (s, e) => ((TreeView)s).SelectedNode = null;
}
```